# Как сделать выдачу только по пересечениям шаблона поиска?

Tags: запрос, mysql

Не могу разобраться с запросом, как сделать его правильным?
Вот пример:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`items_id`)
  FROM `items`
  LEFT JOIN `rubric` ON `rubric`.`items` = `items_id`
  LEFT JOIN `brands`  ON `brands`.`items` = `items_id`
  LEFT JOIN `theme` ON `theme_id_items` = `items_id`
  WHERE 
    (`rubric`='15' OR `rubric`='46' OR `rubric`='47' OR `rubric`='49')
  AND
    (
      (`theme_id_value`='1408697045dizel' AND `theme_id_theme`='1')
        AND
      (`theme_id_value`='1408735817ruchnaya' AND `theme_id_theme`='3')
        AND
      (`theme_id_value_int` >= '100000' AND
       `theme_id_value_int` <= '200000' AND
       `theme_id_theme`='9')
    )
```

Мне надо сделать так, чтобы выдавало только пересечения по шаблонам поиска, т.е. есть некий шаблон с базой забитых данных, я в форме выбираю определенные параметры, и нужно, чтобы выдавало только пересечения в запросе.

`theme_id_value` и `theme_id_value_int` - это поля для выборки, а вот `theme_id_theme` - это сам шаблон, отвечающий за некий фильтр. Как сделать так, чтобы запрос стал рабочим?

Comment: Так пересечение - это когда и там, и там. А по запросу вам надо или там, или там, т.к. `theme_id_theme` не может принимать сразу несколько значений.

Т.е. между скобками с `theme_id_value` поставьте `OR` и будет вам счастье

Comment: `theme_id_value`='1408697045dizel' - довольно сомнительное поле...зачем хранить в таком виде?

а по делу, да, у вас `theme_id_theme`='1' AND `theme_id_theme`='3', ведь в `theme_id_theme` не может одновременно храниться 1 и 3, поэтому ваше условие не срабатывает всегда